# How can i do a gradle publish on teamcity to publish a gradle build that uses the maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, teamcity

I have teamcity currently configured to use the maven mojo, to publish the gradle jar as a nexus snapshot with just the gav.

I observe that if i use the maven plugin and do a gradle install in the IDE, i am able to see the generated pom.

1) Can i use this pom to publish the jar in nexus repo in teamcity ? I know that i can do it for a pure maven build by using it's pom.

2) Is there a way to not use this pom, and istead configure teamcity build steps to publish from gradle build directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle can of course take care of the publication. It will leverage the build information to produce a POM file that represents best what is declared in your project.

It will then be trivial to invoke that Gradle task from the Teamcity build.

Have a look at [the publishing documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/userguide/publishing_setup.html) for details on how to set it up.